# Cracked tile repair -wire mesh on plywood left after removal -should I put cement back over the mesh or there is a better way to fix this?

Tags: tile

I am removing a cracked tile. Under this, after removing the cement previously used I am now seeing wire mesh on plywood. Should I put cement back over the mesh or there is a better way to fix this?[image]
Really poor job by the installer, I should move around on tiptoes after seeing this
**Update:**
Ready for thinset. BTW I am being told somewhere else that the wire mesh should be first embedded in a bed of cement (he used the word mud) and only after that you should install thinset
[image]

Comment: Is the wire right on the plywood or raise up a bit?  It seems like there was not enough pressure applied during installation.

Comment: Yeah it is a litle bit elevated but that could br because I am pulling up theexisting thin set. The wire did not seem to have been attached to the plywood

Comment: Thinset, not cement. It should be *pushed through* the mesh with the trowel, not just laid on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove as much of the thinset as possible from the plywood. Then spread the thinset on and into the plywood/mesh. Also add thinset to the back of the tile, back butter it. You can tell from your picture that not enough thinset was applied and the tile only grabbed the thinset in a few spots, leaving hollow sections under the tile. That's probably why it cracked.

Comment: Looks like thinset over some grout at the bottom. This isn't the first time it's been replaced. *why* it's cracked is yet TBD.... other than *um, that's not how you do it.*

Comment: trust me it has never been repaired

Comment: @JACK should I stable the wire mesh to the plywood ?

Comment: @MiniMe The mesh needs to be secured to the plywood but you want to get the thinset behind it.

Comment: @MiniMe  I never heard about covering mesh with cement and then using thinset over it for the tiles..... unless tiling a sidewalk :-)

Comment: See this: https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=1589369&postcount=2

Comment: I think I would actually slip some lengths of wire behind the mesh, to stand it off from the plywood, rather than stapling it down.